# textfield and tableview cell to active button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uinavigationbar

1.In Facebook iOS app, when one opens a new post but without any content inputted, the Post button in the upper right corner is not active. It will be active immediately after one inputs any content. How to implement that effect?

2.I want to make a page with many tags name as the cell contents, user can choose some tags to filter the contents. Basically, there are two section, selected section and unselected section. When user touches a cell in unselected section, it will fly to the selected section. I hope to active the GO button in the upper right corner only when there is at least one cell in the selected section (Initially, all the tag names are in the unselected section). So how to implement it to let the tableview cell to effect the GO button in the navigation bar? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code... Explained by the comments in the code.

**In `viewDidLoad`**

```
textField.delegate = self; //sets delegate to this file so it calls the method below
```

**In `.h` file**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> //makes it so we can set the delegate
```

**In `.m` file**

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)aTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { //method that gets called on edit
if([textField.text length] > 0) { //if contains characters
tabBarButton.enabled = YES; //set enabled
} 
else { //if not
tabBarButton.enabled = NO; //set disabled
}
return YES;
}
```

You will have to change `tabBarButton` and `textField` accordingly since these are variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enabled` property of UIButton and detect when the button will be enabled or not.

For UITextView, probably you have a delegate method that can help you. Read all delegate methods from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html). For example, you can use `textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` method. Inside it, you can enable your button only if `[textView.text length]` is greater than 0.

For the second answer, you should have a model (probably an array) where you store the selected tags. The correct way of managing your button's state, should be using [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), detecting every time the model changes and enabling the button only if there is items in the array. Another aproach should be use the same method where you add or remove items from the model, to enable or disable your button properly.

Excuse me for my english, but i hope this answer helps!